# How to update nested serializer field with many=True

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm having trouble in updating the serializer data that have nested serializer field, please if someone have any idea to it with best practice i will appreciate your answer!

```
Class ModelA(models.Model):
    field1 = m2mfield
    field2 = m2mfield
    name = charField

class SerializerA(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     anyfielda = serializers.CharField()

class SerializerB(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     anyfieldb = serializers.CharField()
     nested_field = SerializerA(required=True, many=True)
```

How to implement the update method please guide! I'm able to do create but update does not allowed as it is asking for ListSerializer must, I want to know if there is any other way!

Comment: Can you share your current `update` implementation, and the full traceback on the error you get?

Comment: Can you add the content in the models.py here?